# MySQL virtually calculated column for ranking

Tags: mysql, calculated-columns

I have a table that saves user scores in games, structured like this:

```
user_id (int)
game_id (int)
score (int)
```

I want to add another column to this table which will be a virtual column that holds the ranking of user for a game (like a table).

For example

```
user_id game_id score rank (virtual)
      1       1    50    1
      2       1    48    2
      3       1    40    3
      2       2    80    1
      1       2    50    2
      3       2    32    3
```

As you can see, the rank column is virtually calculated by the points in each game.

Is it even possible? And if so, what should I write in the virtuality expression field?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible to use a generated column for calculating rank. As MySQL documentation on [generated columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) says:

> Subqueries, parameters, variables, stored functions, and user-defined functions are not permitted.

To calculate the rank, you would have to determine the position of the record using a certain ordering within the entire table. This would require an expression that can check other records. There are no such functions within MySQL and subqueries are not allowed.

The only way to make this work is via a view, where you are allowed to use variables and subqueries to calculate the ranking.

Note, that this may change with MySQL v8.0 because it has [rank()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_rank) and dense_rank() functions. You have to experiment whether these functions are allowed in generated columns (I'm not sure if they are deterministic).

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't account for ties, but may get you started...

```
SELECT x.*
     , CASE WHEN @prev = game_id THEN @i:=@i+1 ELSE @i:=1 END rank
     , @prev := game_id
  FROM my_table
     , (SELECT @prev:=null,@i:=0) vars
 ORDER
    BY gamed_id, score DESC;
```

Comment: That's a query, I meant is it possible to do so as a virtually calculated column from PMA?

Comment: @Daniel What's the difference?

Comment: Not much of a difference. I'm familiar with the way you suggested, I was just wondering if there's a way to achieve the same result with the virtuality feature of PMA.

Comment: I see. At the risk of being shot down in flames, I'm going to say I don't think it's possible.

Comment: PMA does not have a virtual column feature, MySQL does.

Comment: @Strawberry you will not be shot down, it is not possible. See my answer for details.